# Plot using a list of variables

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
vars = {\[Alpha][1], \[Alpha][2], \[Alpha][3], \[Alpha][4]};
f = (vars[[1]] vars[[4]]^1 + vars[[2]] vars[[4]]^2 + 
vars[[3]] vars[[4]]^3) /. {vars[[1]] -> 1, vars[[2]] -> 2, 
vars[[3]] -> 3};
Plot[f, {Last[vars], 0, 10}]
```

Mathematica 10.2 returns the error

```
Plot::write: Tag Last in Last[vars] is Protected. >>
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Do this: `Plot[f,Evaluate@{Last[vars],0,10}]`. The reason is that `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll`, it doesn't execute the `Last` command with which you intended to extract the name of the plot variable. Instead, it continues to evaluate the plot expression as if the plot variable were named `Last[vars]`, which is not allowed according to what the error message correctly states.

To get around this issue, you therefore have to explicitly force the `Last[vars]` to be evaluated before the enclosing `Plot` is called. This can be done with [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html), but only if it is placed correctly. You can't put `Evaluate` directly in front of `Last` because then it too will be part of the argument that is held. That argument is the entire list `{Last[vars],0,10}`, and it is therefore what has to be preceded by `Evaluate`.

This is stated in the documentation for `Evaluate`:

> ... only overrides ... attributes when it appears directly as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held

In summary, what you can do is this:

```
Plot[f,Evaluate@{Last[vars],0,10}]
```